# Can I create automatic Unit Tests for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, automated-tests

> When I create a program using C# and VS2008 , then I can create a test case just by Rightclicking on the method. But I am not sure If I can create the tests in the same way if it is a C++ project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the lack of reflection in C++, you propably wont be able to have these kind of unit tests, VS provides.

Comment: What you don't get is automatically generated test functions/stubs -- you can certainly use unit testing functionality in Visual Studio for C++ -- even Native/Unmanaged C++.  You just have to call your native functions from C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't. You can create a C++/CLI test project and tests manually though.  The IDE will create a C++/CLI test class with stubs etc. for you.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answers above, just adding...or use the **boost library**:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/test/doc/components/utf/index.html

Comment: Might I add here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965864/what-is-your-favorite-recommended-project-structure-and-file-structure-for-unit-t/3584680#3584680

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at CppUnit or googletest for unit testing with C++. You won't have the IDE generation of test cases, but there are unit testing frameworks out there.